# "rake" command using ruboto returns abort and permission denied

Tags: android, ruby, rake, dx, ruboto

I've recently decided to venture into android app development with ruboto. I installed the Android SDK with all the necessary development tools along with jruby, javac, ant, and ruboto. However, when I call the "rake" (ruby make) command, I get the following error:

```
morgan@ubuntu:~/quick_start$ rake
rake aborted!
Permission denied - /home/morgan/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/dx
/home/morgan/quick_start/rakelib/ruboto.rake:27:in `initialize'
/home/morgan/quick_start/rakelib/ruboto.rake:27:in `open'
/home/morgan/quick_start/rakelib/ruboto.rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/morgan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/morgan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

etc...
It seems that the problem originates with the dx file within my android platform-tools... I was wondering if anyone has had any similar problems and how I would go about finding a solution so that I may run "rake" and generate a .apk file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was addressed recently by checking existence and file permissions of the dx command.  It should work with the latest Ruboto release.

If you still have problems, please file an issue at https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/issues